# How to remove an array over the object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, javascript-objects

I'm receiving a response like this from the api, which is not a desired response for mapping

```
[
    [
      {
        fullname: 'Abc',
        email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        phone: '03000000000',
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        fullname: 'edf',
        email: 'edf@gmail.com',
        phone: '03000000000',
      },
    ],
  ]
```

I want to remove the array over each object like this

```
[
      {
          fullname: 'Abc',
        email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        phone: '03000000000',
      },
      {
        fullname: 'edf',
        email: 'edf@gmail.com',
        phone: '03000000000',
      },
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `let result = data.map( el => el[0])`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!